Is there optimal or approximate solution to Single-machine scheduling problem with constraints?
I'm interested in particular setup of Single-machine scheduling. I'll use the Optimal job scheduling notation to specify the situation. I'm also aware of Interval scheduling.
What I want to achieve is a weekly task planner for myself that'd be flexible and adaptable to various constraints.
Assumptions/constraints:

single-stage jobs - each job j consists of a single execution phase
1: Single-machine scheduling - my own time is the only resource
pj the processing time is varying for each job
wj jobs can be weighted - for example have a fixed priority assigned
prec - there are no restrictions placed on the precedence relations
tj - there are no transportation delays

One particular extension that'd be especially nice is to have jobs/intervals partitioned into groups (to have different variants of the same job, e.g. jobA lasting 15 mins, jobA lasting 30 mins, jobA lasting 45 mins) - Group Interval Scheduling Maximization.
Another one could be with inclusion of dj (due date) or d̅j (strict deadline).
I'm interested in exploring different objective functions for above stated situation. If they can be solved using different methods I'd like to get overview of those (ideally the same parametrizable solution could solve different goals).
Example objective functions:

no objective value. This means that the problem consists simply in producing a feasible scheduling, satisfying all given constraints.
Cj - minimize the sum of completion times
wjCj - minimize the weighted sum of completion times
Lmax - minimize the maximum lateness
...

In practice my problem space is somewhat limited:

7 days in week, 16 hours a day
let's say a job cannot be shorter than 15 minutes: 7 * 16 * 4 = 448 time slots
some jobs have hard constraints (cannot be moved) so they effectively reduce problem space as everything needs to be scheduled around them

I'm curious whether for this particular setup an optimal or aproximate solution is known? What are some classes of algorithm that could be used to tackle such setup? I've been thinking about Genetic algorithms or Simulated annealing. I've also thought about framing it in Reinforcement learning framework and solving using Proximal_policy_optimization  or similar.
